# Adding class in table in ckeditor for rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I want to add a class named "table" to the table that is created by default. I also want to change the value of border from table dialogue box of ckeditor. I am in big trouble.

Comment: you need to explain a bit more about your problem, what you've tried, what was the outcome etc. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if (dialogName === 'table') {
    var addCssClass = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced').get('advCSSClasses');
    addCssClass['default'] = 'table-class';
  }
});
```

Comment: may need to add -> if (dialogName === 'table' || dialogName == 'tableProperties')