# CKEDITOR Support for Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I would like to add support to CKEDITOR v4.0 for Bootstrap tables. But this could also come under a more general styling situation.

I have enabled tables in CKEDITOR and want to assign a custom class to any table generated in the editor.

for example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
```

should become:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
```

How do I go about doing this with tables in CKEDITOR?

I have tried using data processors as found in the documentation, however they don't work for table elements.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor

```
CKEDITOR.replace(myElement, {
    ...
    on: {
        loaded: function (e) {
            var rules = {
                elements: {
                    table: function (element) {
                        // Add bootstrap table class to ckeditor tables
                        $(element).addClass('table');
                    }
                }
            };
            e.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules(rules);
            e.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(rules);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592482/adding-class-in-table-in-ckeditor-for-rails-application)

If you want the user to be able to change the class of a table from within the editor you can add to styles.js file in your ckeditor folder this:

```
{ name: 'My Table Class', element: 'table', attributes: { 'class': 'myTableClass' } }
```